# Recommended Books for ASP.NET performance optimization and testing

Tags: asp.net

What would be a recommended book for ASP.NET performance optimization and testing?

tks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Packtpub.ASP.NET.Site.Performance.Secrets

Here is table of content:
http://www.packtpub.com/toc/aspnet-site-performance-secrets-table-contents